# Efficient way to get number of part numbers used from MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table for inventory

```
id | part_number
----------------
1  | R101
2  | E763
3  | H293
4  | N837
5  | Y121
6  | U837
```

a table for order items

```
id | order_id | quantity | price
--------------------------------
1  |   1      |   3      |  45
2  |   1      |   6      |  20
3  |   1      |   10     |  10
4  |   2      |   3      |  22
5  |   2      |   8      |  10
6  |   3      |   87     |  98
```

and a table for orders item part numbers

```
id | order_items_id | inventory_id
----------------------------------
1   |     1         |      1
2   |     1         |      3
3   |     2         |      2
4   |     2         |      3
5   |     2         |      1
6   |     3         |      4
7   |     3         |      5
8   |     3         |      1
9   |     4         |      2
10  |     4         |      3
11  |     5         |      1
12  |     5         |      4
13  |     6         |      2
14  |     6         |      4
15  |     6         |      5
```

I have a procedure that will get each part number and the number of times it is used but it takes a long time to run once these tables get very large.  I want to come up with an efficient procedure that will return this information in real time.

```
part_number | number_of_times_used
----------------------------------
R101        |     27
E763        |     96
H293        |     12
N837        |     105
Y121        |     97
U837        |     0
```

Comment: Well, without seeing your queries (or the procedure), and what fields may (or may not) be indexed, we need more information.

Comment: In which part of your tables which part_number_id has. What i mean is the foreign key of it.

Comment: There are no part numbers in order items part number - and it's unusual (though perhaps not unheard of) to store price where you do

Comment: Is id in the second table actually part number id?

Answer (score 0):

First start with what you SHOULD have. The tables should be appropriately indexed. Assuming that order_items_id is a reference to order_items.id and order_id is a reference to parts.id, you should have primary indices on the tables - for parts,  primary index on id, for order_items index on id.

Then you could create foreign keys on your order_item_part_numbers - index order_items_part_number.order_items_id to the foreign key order_items.id, and index order_items_part_number.inventory_id to the foreign key parts.id.

Once you have the tables appropriately indexed, you should get fairly good performance in your query:

```
select part_number, sum(quantity) as numnber_of_items_used
from order_items
join order_items_part_number on order_item.id=order_items_part_number.order_items_id
join parts on parts.id=order_items_part_number.inventory_id
group by part_number
```